# Finding usages of a method in multiple Visual Studio solutions

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, reference

Suppose I have a Visual Studio solution called `MySolution`. `MySolution` contains a project with a public method defined like this: `public void MyMethod(){...}`.

If I have Resharper installed I can find the usages of `MyMethod` in `MySolution` by right clicking it and choosing **Find Usages**. However, suppose I have a number of other Visual Studio solutions on my hard drive which may or may not make use of `MyMethod`. Is there a simple way to track down these usages?

EDIT: Here's an attempted clarification of what I'm looking for. Suppose we have two other solutions `MySolution2` and `MySolution3`. Each of these solutions contains a number of projects. Some of these projects may reference the assembly containing `MyMethod`. Let's call these projects *referring* projects. Some of the referring projects may actually make direct use of `MyMethod`. Let's call these projects *client* projects. I'm both interested in finding the referring projects (less ambitious) and the client projects (more ambitious).

Comment: If your code is under TFS 2015 Update 2 (VSTS, or I think on-prem in the future), you can use the [Code Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search) extension to find references.

Comment: Currently the best answer is there isn't one, but there should be. With my knowledge of Roslyn it would not be that hard to do either a hard drive/workspace Find All References or a TFS/git repo Find All References. It's just a matter of free time.

Answer (score 1):

How would the other solutions make use of MyMethod other than having its containing assembly referenced in the end?
If you mean is there a way to know if a particular method from a particular assembly referenced from a particular project is actually used in this project or not, then no, to my knowledge there's no way to do that other than going to each of these solutions, jumping to the method (say, with ReSharper's Go to symbol) and searching for its usages.